# httpOnly cookies are shown in browser console

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, httponly

My express app is running on localhost:4000 and is setting two cookies like this:

```
res.cookie('accessToken',token, { maxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: false,Path: './',SameSite: 'None' });
res.cookie('refreshToken',_token, { maxAge: 86400000, httpOnly: true, secure:false,Path: './',SameSite: 'None' });
```

secure is false since I am on localhost but httpOnly is set to true.

Looking at network tab on localhost:80 I expected not to have any cookie displayed but I can see the cookies displayed and with the httpOnly flag set to true. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: _"Looking at network tab on localhost:80 I expected not to have any cookie displayed"_ - why ...? You are looking at something _in the network tab_, don't you think what's shown there would involve HTTP?

Comment: (httpOnly means that JavaScript running _in the website context_ doesn't get access. It has nothing to do with whether other parts of the _browser_, like dev tools, can see it.)

Comment: @CBroe ok, so any user can see the values by using the browser console? and use it by copy pasting the value if he is a malicious user. it is not accessible by client javascript but by user yes?

Comment: Anything that is sent or received by a client can be accessed and used maliciously if an actor has access to it. Cookies aren't secret and yes, can be read by the browser, how else would the browser send them along? Encryption is only relevant while travelling from A to B, but both A and B need access to the shared information.

Comment: so the assumption "save refresh token on http-only cookie to store it securely" is not completely true and is valid only until someone get access to the user browser. After that he can impersonate the user till the refresh token is valid, correct?

Comment: httpOnly doesn't have the purpose of hiding anything from your website user, but to prevent access by 3rd parties. Many websites embed scripts from external sources, that they do not have control over - like for example script to embed ads. Ad servers have been hacked and used to distribute malicious JS code before.

Comment: _"only until someone get access to the user browser. After that he can impersonate the user till the refresh token is valid, correct?"_ - if I already got physical access to your browser, then of course I can do anything on the page, that you could do as well.